# How to translate Django app

Tags: python, django, macos, python-2.7, localization

I'm trying to add a translation (localization) layer to my appliaction.
I have tried to follow the instructions from: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/i18n/translation/#how-to-create-language-files

But I run in some problems when I tried to run

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l he
```

In order to create a translation file for Hebrew.

When I first run this code I got the following error:

```
CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.
```

So I run the command:

```
brew install gettext
```

But I still got an error:

```
CommandError: Can't find msguniq. Make sure you have GNU gettext tools 0.15 or newer installed.
```

So I saw in some places that I need to run:

```
brew link gettext --force
```

Now when I try to run the command:

```
django-admin.py makemessages -l he
```

I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    pkg_resources.run_script('Django==1.7.1', 'django-admin.py')
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 492, in run_script
    self.require(requires)[0].run_script(script_name, ns)
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/pkg_resources.py", line 1350, in run_script
    execfile(script_filename, namespace, namespace)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/EGG-INFO/scripts/django-admin.py", line 5, in <module>
    management.execute_from_command_line()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 385, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 377, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **options.__dict__)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 338, in execute
    output = self.handle(*args, **options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/base.py", line 533, in handle
    return self.handle_noargs(**options)
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 283, in handle_noargs
    potfiles = self.build_potfiles()
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 299, in build_potfiles
    file_list = self.find_files(".")
  File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/Django-1.7.1-py2.7.egg/django/core/management/commands/makemessages.py", line 358, in find_files
    ignored_roots = [os.path.normpath(p) for p in (settings.MEDIA_ROOT, settings.STATIC_ROOT)]
  File "/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 327, in normpath
    initial_slashes = path.startswith('/')
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'starts with'
```

I'm using a Mac with Django 1.7 and Python 2.7.6

please help to understand what I'm missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try for instance `python ../manage.py makemessages -l en` inside your app

`django-admin.py` didn't work for me either

Answer (score 1):

You should point django to your project's `settings.py` file.

```
export DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE=/path/to/settings.py
```